# Как передать методы класса в другой класс (iOS 7 на storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Ситуация такая, есть клас `Class : UIViewController` у него есть метод, к примеру

```
- (void)displayRefresh
{

}
```

Как этот метод вызвать в другом классе `Class2 : UIViewController` в методе:

```
- (IBAction)display:(id)sender
{

}
```

Вопросы:

1. Как вызвать?
2. Что для этого нужно?

Comment: В втором классе нужна ссылка на созданный объект первого класса.

Comment: Как ваши контроллеры между собой связаны? Обычно используются три способа связи контроллеров между собой:

1.Модальное представление - один контроллер презентует другой (modal presentation).
2.Родитель-ребенок - отношения т.н. Controller Containment.
3.Вы используете navigation controller и осуществляете push-переход от одного к другому (руками или посредством performSegueWithIdentifier).

Скорее всего ваш способ будет тяготеть к одному из этого списка. Я мог бы описать способы связи для всех этих случаев, но всё-таки хочу сначала узнать про ваш.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, Использую переход по ячейке из Table View, а в Class2 содержаться детальное отображения данных, которые выбрал из таблицы - я надеюсь понятно описал)

Comment: А можете zip тестового проекта выложить куда-нибудь на файлообменник и ссылку на него добавить в вопрос?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, Сейчас нет такой возможности, так как не дома. Вообще только не давно начал изучать iOS разработку, по этому могу чего-то не так писать :)

Там должно быть не тяжело, просто нужно метод передать в другой класс, а как вообще передают методы с одного класса в другой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[@leonid3452](/users/14328/leonid3452)](/users/14328/leonid3452), Доброе время суток! Постараюсь объяснить на своём примере. Допустим есть два класса:

```
"ViewController : UIViewController" и "DetailController : UIViewController"
```

И нам нужно передать метод:

```
- (void)displayLog с "ViewController" в "DetailController"
```

И так, переходим к реализации: 1 что нужно сделать убедиться что метод объявлен в "ViewController.h" примерно будет выглядеть так:

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{

}
- (void) displayLog;
@end
```

Переходим в ViewController.m реализуем метод:

```
//ViewController.m
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void) displayLog
{
     NSLog(@"Hello");
}
@end
```

Далее нужно вызвать этот метод (- (void) displayLog;) в DetailController, скажем по нажатию на кнопку, реализуем:

```
//DetailController.h
@interface DetailController : UIViewController
{

}
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@end
```

Переходим в .m:

```
//DetailController.m
@interface DetailPassword ()
@end

@implementation DetailPassword

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *viewCon = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [viewCon displayLog];
}
@end
```

Я надеюсь что понятно объяснил. Если что не поняли, задавайте вопросы.

Comment: @Ковальский, спасибо вам большое, прям большущее!!! все заработало, спасибо, благодарю вас!!! Вопросов пока что нету, всё вроде бы как понятно :))

Comment: @leonid3452, Абсолютно не за что.

Comment: Можно и так, но для этих целей существует делегирование.

Comment: Я собирался рассказывать про делегирование и прочие рекомендуемые дела, но, если автору хватило этого, значит хватило))

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, Расскажите мне, я тоже не давно начал изучать, ещё не всё понятно, а я буду Вам очень благодарен, или если можно какую-то сылочку на статью :)

Comment: Развернутый ответ мне сейчас писать долго, так как занят, поэтому и просил исходник, чтобы показать на примере конкретного случая ТС.

Comment: Для самого общего случая связи двух контроллеров (да и любых двух классов), действительно, делегирование - самый оптимальный способ.

Comment: Для немного более частных случаев связи именно между контроллерами (я описал основные в комменте к вопросу) есть более "родные способы" - но их использование зависит от того, как конкретно связаны между собой контроллеры.